# Transform variadic type list to tuple of pairs

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++20

Is the following type transformation possible:

```
T1, T2, T3, T4, ...., T2n-1, T2n 
    ---> transform to --->
tuple<
  pair<T1, T2>, 
  pair<T3, T4>, 
  ..., 
  pair<T2n-1, T2n>
>
```

Such a meta-function

```cpp
template <class... Args>
using split_in_pairs_t = ???
```

would be used like so:

```cpp
template <class... Args>
class UseCase
{
  split_in_pairs_t<Args...> _tupleOfPairs;
};
```

A non-recursive solution would be preferable.

Comment: Which C++ version is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an index sequence of half the size, and pair elements `2*i, 2*i+1` together:

```cpp
template <class...> struct pairwise_impl;

template <class... Args, size_t... Is> 
struct pairwise_impl<std::tuple<Args...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using full_tuple_t = std::tuple<Args...>;
    
    using type = std::tuple<std::pair<
        std::tuple_element_t<2*Is, full_tuple_t>,
        std::tuple_element_t<2*Is+1, full_tuple_t>
    >...>;
};

template <class... Args> struct pairwise
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) % 2 == 0,
                   "Only even typelists can be split to pairs");
    
    using type = typename pairwise_impl<
        std::tuple<Args...>, 
        std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) / 2>
    >::type;           
};  

template <class... Args>
using pairwise_t = typename pairwise<Args...>::type;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4885303d5c398521)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_pairwise_foldl_f), this is a short one-liner (as always):

```cpp
template <class... Args>
using split_in_pairs_t =
    mp_pairwise_fold<std::tuple<Args...>, std::pair>;
```

Comment: That's so nice. I was looking at Hana for something similar, but judging from `boost.mp` it is probably not that obvious on how to formulate this stuff as folds.